# What does ~ means in Java?

Tags: java, javafx

Searching on the documentation of [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) in `JavaFX` i walked through this method:

```
     /**
     * Set all dirty bits
     */
    private void setDirty() {
        dirtyBits = ~0;
    }

   //where dirtyBits is an int
```

I have searched on search engine but can't find what `~` means?

Comment: There is a problem with search engines and computer programming operators. Most search engines (Google, notably) remove punctuation from searches, thus you can't look for operators. You might want to search using [Symbolhound](http://symbolhound.com/).

Comment: @RealSkeptic I agree, searching for "java operators" is very hard and almost impossible to find pages like http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm.

Comment: @RealSkeptic http://symbolhound.com/?q=what+%7E+means+in+Java%3F bring no results again.I didn't knew that search engines remove the punctuation (+1).

Comment: @Tom you are being sarcastic, but beginners usually have to understand it's actually an *operator* to search for the word "operator". Another way is to search for "java tilde", which Google understands, but there are many people who don't know the *name* of the `~` character. So really, there is no place for sarcasm here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is a the unary bitwise operator, changes in binary each `0` by `1` and each `1` by `0`

From [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html)

> **The unary bitwise complement operator "~" inverts a bit pattern**; it can be applied to any of the integral types, making every "0" a "1" and every "1" a "0".
>
> For example, a byte contains 8 bits; applying this operator to a value whose bit pattern is `00000000` would change its pattern to `11111111`.

---

As stated in comments, problem of this is not lack of effort by user either documentation but problem of the search engines like google because remove punctuation symbols (like `~`) when searching.

For people like me, non English native speakers is a real problem sometimes to find **the correct words**. In order to avoid this, in this case, you can  search [java bitwise operator](https://www.google.es/search?q=java%20bitwise%20operator&oq=java%20bitwise%20operator&aqs=chrome..69i57.272j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for further info.